# Set properties of multiple different JButtons in a loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, jbutton, subclassing

```
String[] objectName = {  //these are all names for JButtons
            "firstBtn",
            "secondBtn",
            "thirdBtn",
            "coin1",
            "coin5",
            "coin25",
            "coin100"
    };    

for (int k=0;k<objectName.length;k++){
    objectName[o].setOpaque(false);
    objectName[o].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    objectName[o].setBorderPainted(false);
}
```

I was trying to shorten code in this way because i thought it would be easier. However it does not work. Is there a way to make this code work or do i have to write the same thing again and again for each JButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could subclass `JButton` and do the following,

```
public class MyButton extends JButton{
    public MyButton(){
        setOpaque(false);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setBorderPainted(false);
    }
}
```

and then create instances,

```
JButton firstBtn = new MyButton();
.
.
```

Comment: From what I remember it is good practice to invoke super() constructor inside GUI derived classes constructor to ensure default GUI operations. But I might be wrong.

Comment: This works however it prevents me from initiallizing it as usual (EX. JButton btn = new JButton("EXAMPLE");)

Comment: @Exikle instead `public MyButton(){setOpaque(false); ...` try `public MyButton(String text){ super(text); setOpaque(false); //and rest of your operations}`. This constructor will let you create object of `MyButton` class with title as parameter so you will be able to use it like `JButton btn = new MyButton("YourName");`